# Return objects with unique keys from array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, reduce

How do I get from:

`let items = [ { id: 1, name: 'one'}, { id: 60, name 'sixty'}]`

to:

`{ 1: { id: 1, name: 'one' }, 60: { id: 60, name: 'sixty' } }`

*I don't really mind the duplication of the id for this question.*

I've tried this:

```
items.reduce((allItems, item) => {
   return allItems[item.id] = item;
}, {});
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object

But it doesn't work as the example suggests... does reduce only work for arrays of single items, not objects?

Any suggestion how to return a key from a map, or some `lodash` function that can do this for me? (i.e. practically returning `[item.id]: { ...item}`, but then flatten them like the above object outcome, with unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I should not return it right away:

```
items.reduce((allItems, item) => {
   allItems[item.id] = item;
   return allItems;
}, {});
```